# MySQL update with variable

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am encountering a problem while updating a table.
The code is from telegram bot. We are receiving messages from user, and asking him for a name. This is the variable 'first_name'. We already know his user_id which is integer.
Then I am trying to do

```
def bd_set(body):
    cursor.execute(body)
    connect.commit()

bd_set(f"INSERT INTO user_info (user_id,first_name) VALUES({user_id},{first_name})")
```

and getting an error:
`no such column "John".`

But if I try without variable, the code works:

```
bd_set(f"INSERT INTO user_info (user_id,first_name) VALUES({user_id},'John')")
```

So, I cannot input varibale (first_name), while variable'user_id' inputs easily.

what can solve the issue?

Comment: OP, I _strongly_ urge you to use the parameterized version of the query I show in my answer instead of the one you have accepted. SQL injection is very serious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with quotation marks. As first_name is a string, and as you are using f string, you need to use quotation marks

```
bd_set(f"INSERT INTO user_info (user_id,first_name) VALUES({user_id},'{first_name}')")
```

You should try to use prepared statements to avoid this kind of problems and to avoid sql injection

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question and in both existing answers has the same major problem: they are *wide open* to a serious security vulnerability called [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Don't build SQL queries by sticking strings together.

Instead, pass the parameters to `cursor.execute()` separately:

```py
def bd_set(body, parameters=None):
    cursor.execute(body, parameters)
    connect.commit()

bd_set(
    f"INSERT INTO user_info (user_id, first_name) VALUES(%s, %s)",
    (user_id, first_name),
)
```

I replaced the placeholders here with `%s` but depending on your database driver you might have to use [different syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle).